# JavaScript expression to find index of object in array shows error in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I am using trying to find the index of an `Object` in an `Array` of `Objects` in JavaScript.

Code to find the index of the array depending on the user role:

```
function getUserIndex(arr, value) {
    return arr.findIndex(x => x._user_role == value);
}
```

the Array looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_user_role": "xxx",
        "_id": "0"
    },
    {
        "_user_role": "xxxx",
        "_id": "2"
    },
    {
        "_user_role": "xxxxx",
        "_id": "4"
    },
    {
        "_user_role": "xxxxx",
        "_id": "6"
    }
]
```

Everything works fine and I am using WebStorm IDE.

The only problem is that I see that some expression inside of `findIndex` are marked red indicating some kind of error, but everything work fine as expected.

[image]

Do anyone know how to fix this? Even if this does not cause any issue the red marks don't look good, so I want to remove them.

Comment: What version of webstorm are you using? It may not support ecmascript 6

Comment: @Pat I am using 9.0.4

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Make sure you've [enabled ES6/ES2015](https://medium.com/@brandonaaskov/enabling-es6-syntax-support-in-webstorm-48e22956ecfd#.5opi3vm6g) in WebStorm.

Comment: @MikeC Thank you that was it